# Javascript inheritance: calling parent method automatically if property name are the same

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Is there a way to call parent method automatically if the property name are the same.

```
// library part
var parent = {
    foo: function() { console.log('foo from parent'); },
    bar: function() { console.log('bar from parent'); }
}

// User part
var child = Object.create(parent);

child.foo = function() { console.log('foo from child'); };
child.bar = function() { console.log('bar from child'); };
```

The output if i call `child.foo()` is `foo from child`, and my objective output is both `foo from child` and `foo from parent` is console logged out. For now when i need to do that, i use this code:

```
child.foo = function() {
     console.log('foo from child');
     this.__proto__.foo();
}
```

I have a reason to do that, it's like library that provide a parent object that can be extended by the user and i don't want to remind the user to call `this.__proto__.foo()` every time they assign the method which the property name are the same with the property from parent object.

The solution must be modifying the library part of course (parent object or maybe in object creation), not the user part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Re your edit

> The solution must be modifying the library part of course (parent object or maybe in object creation), not the user part.

If that means you really want the users to be able to write

```
child.foo = function() { ... };
```

...then that changes things a bit, but it's still possible without resorting to proxies (which are *really* slow). First, my original answer, since you'd accepted it, then an update accounting for that:

---

### Original Answer

> i don't want to remind the user to call `this.__proto__.foo()` every time they assign the method which the property name are the same with the property from parent object

In that case, you probably want to give them a worker function they use to set those function properties, and automatically detect the situation and handle it. You'll have to decide whether to call the prototype's version before or after the user's new code, if you're not going to let them control where the call goes, and decide whether to return the result of their function or the prototype's.

Naturally, nothing prevents them from choosing to ignore that, but there's only so much you can do.

For instance, this example assumes you want to call the original *after* (as shown in your example) and return the result of their override.

```js
var mainProto = {
    addMethod: function(name, method) {
        var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(this); // See note later
        if (typeof p[name] === "function") {
            this[name] = function() {
                var result = method.apply(this, arguments);
                p[name].apply(this, arguments);
                return result;
            };
        } else {
            this[name] = method;
        }
        return this;
    }
};
var parent = Object.create(mainProto);
parent.addMethod("foo", function foo() { console.log('foo from parent'); });
parent.addMethod("bar", function bar() { console.log('bar from parent'); });
var child = Object.create(parent);
child.addMethod("foo", function foo() { console.log('foo from child'); });
child.addMethod("bar", function bar() { console.log('bar from child'); });
var grandChild = Object.create(child);
grandChild.addMethod("foo", function foo() { console.log('foo from grandChild'); });
grandChild.addMethod("bar", function bar() { console.log('bar from grandChild'); });

console.log("---");
parent.foo();
parent.bar();
console.log("---");
child.foo();
child.bar();
console.log("---");
grandChild.foo();
grandChild.bar();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

About `__proto__` vs `getPrototypeOf`: `__proto__` is officially only supported on browsers, not in other JavaScript environments, and is defined on `Object.prototype` so it's entirely possible to have an object without it (via `Object.create(null)`). In constrast, `getPrototypeOf` is defined across environments and works regardless of whether the object inherits from `Object.prototype`.

---

### Update for edit

We can use a setter on the properties in question to insert our wrappers instead of having the user call `addMethod`:

```js
// Library code
function wrapMethod(newMethod, parentMethod) {
    if (typeof parentMethod === "function") {
        return function() {
            var result = newMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            parentMethod.apply(this, arguments);
            return result;
        };
    }
    return newMethod;
}
function defineMethod(obj, name, method) {
    Object.defineProperty(obj, name, {
        set: function(newValue) {
            if (this === obj) {
                return;
            }
            defineMethod(this, name,wrapMethod(newValue, Object.getPrototypeOf(this)[name]));
        },
        get: function() {
            if (this === obj) {
                return method;
            }
            return this[name];
        }
    });
}
var parent = (function() {
    var _foo = function foo() { console.log("foo from parent"); };
    var _bar = function bar() { console.log("bar from parent"); };
    var parent = {};
    defineMethod(parent, "foo", _foo);
    defineMethod(parent, "bar", _bar);
    return parent;
})();

// User code
var child = Object.create(parent);
child.foo = function foo() { console.log('foo from child'); };
child.bar = function bar() { console.log('bar from child'); };
var grandChild = Object.create(child);
grandChild.foo = function foo() { console.log('foo from grandChild'); };
grandChild.bar = function bar() { console.log('bar from grandChild'); };

console.log("---");
parent.foo();
parent.bar();
console.log("---");
child.foo();
child.bar();
console.log("---");
grandChild.foo();
grandChild.bar();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: That exactly the solution i want, thank you. And about the note, it's actually library for browser only so i don't need to worry about that.

Comment: @billyzaelani: Cool, glad that helped. I read your edit as meaning you wanted user code to be able to do `child.foo = function() { ... }` and so added an alternative that lets you do that (without proxies). But if `addMethod` does the job, it's simpler. :-)

Comment: That's even better, i can used the original one as well because it's modifying object creational or in this case, modifying the method adder.

Comment: "The solution must be modifying the library part of course (parent object or maybe in object creation), not the user part." I think this sentence is not good to describe what i think. Maybe this is the good one, "i don't want to distorted user logic in this case is inside the method `console.log('from child');` which from above is distorted by `this.__proto__.foo()` "

Answer (score 0):

I guess another way to do this, without calling the ***proto*** explicitly would be to use a factory function:

```
const createChild = parent => Object.create(parent);
const enchanceChild = parent => ({
  foo() {
     console.log('from child');
     parent.foo();
  }
});

const parent = {
   foo(){ console.log('from parent') },
}

const child = createChild(parent);
const enchancedChild = enchanceChild(child);

enchancedChild.foo(); // from child form parent
```

It is just another approach of doing what you already did above.

What do you think?

**EDIT:**

Using [Proxy Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) a more cleaner approach:

```
var createObject = parent => {
   var handler = {
      get(target, name) {
         if (typeof target[name] === 'function' && typeof parent[name] === 'function') {
            return function() {
                const res = target[name]();
                parent[name]();
                return res;
            }
         }
         return target[name];
      }
   }

   return new Proxy({}, handler);
}

const parent = { foo() { console.log('parent'); }, };
const child = createObject(parent);

child.foo = () => console.log('child');

child.foo();
// returns:
// child
// parent
```

Comment: Just like you said, it's another approach. But sorry i edited the question, the solution i want is modifying the library part not the user part. so the user part is just like the code above without calling `__proto__`, nothing change, maybe if the pattern when create object can be used if it solve the problem. in your code, the child still calling `parent.foo()`

Comment: ok now I understand what you want. There is a way to achieve this. I recommend looking into *Proxy objects* in javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy with proxy objects you can manipulate what happens when calling a property on the instance and act on it.

Comment: First i need to deep dive into the proxy object because i'm never use that. But it's said "The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc)." So i think it can be work as well, thank you.